# Reducing CPU usage while parsing logs in real time

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm creating a program in Python that keeps tracking a log file in real time, my code is as following:

```
import time
with open('/Users/alexandrelara/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            if line.startswith('[Zone]') and "tag=PLAYSTATE value=LOSING" in line:
                print(line)
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
```

The problem is that the Python process is using about 100% of the CPU, as you can see on this image:

[image: Python Process - CPU Usage]

Putting the thread to sleep for 1 second isn't helping and a value higher than that wouldn't give me the results that I want, since it's a game log and each action results in a lot of lines inside the log.

Is there any way to improve the CPU usage? Or shouldn't I be using Python for this?

Comment: You could do `if line and line.startswith('[Zone'] and "tag=PLAYSTATE value=LOSING" in line:` in one line I think :)
Not that it fixes your problem tho

Comment: Why is this a problem? Don't you want the results as fast as possible? Using less than 100% CPU will give you a longer runtime.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.  Currently I assume that its taking so long since if there is nothing returned by `f.readline()` you *immediately* ask again ... and that's where your 100% loop is happening ... but I can't tell, since its not indented correctly ...

Comment: @Ruben It doesn't fix, the CPU Usage is still in 100%.

Comment: @AlexandreLara I know, I said that too. But just a comment ;)

Comment: @EmilVikström The problem is that is consomes a lot of battery and also the CPU gets too hot using 100% during all the time. Furthermore, it can be too bad for users who don't have a high CPU speed and will run the program while playing.

donkopotamus Thank you, I fixed, it got unformatted when I pasted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using sleep on the else block:

```
import time
with open('/Users/alexandrelara/Library/Logs/Unity/Player.log') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            if line.startswith('[Zone]') and "tag=PLAYSTATE value=LOSING" in line:
                print(line)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: @Kadir Perfect! Now the CPU Usage is about 0.01%, could you explain the magic? I guess that it is because when the log isn't receiving any new lines, I put the thread to sleep, in this case, most of the time the log won't be updated, so I don't need to keep processing it which yields to a much lower CPU Usage than my algorithm.

Comment: @AlexandreLara You are welcome. As you said If the log file is not updated, there would be lots of unnecessary `readline()`, calls in the `while True` statement. Else block prevents it.

Comment: @AlexandreLara This code implements a technique known as ["polling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29). It is like children in a car asking "Are we there yet?". Without the sleep in the else, the children ask non-stop. In software this is known as a ["busy-wait"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy-wait). With the sleep in there they wait one second before asking again.

Comment: Clear answer @Kadir